# Help to prove this is an equivalence relation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 64 he made the following definition:

> **Definition.** Let $\sigma:[c,d]\to \mathbb C$ and $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ be rectifiable paths. The path $\sigma$ is equivalent to
>   $\gamma$ if there is a function $f:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ which is
>   continuous, strictly increasing, and with $f(c)=a,\ f(d)=b$; such that
>   $\sigma=\gamma\circ f$.

I'm trying to prove this is an equivalence relation. I've already proved the symmetric and transitivity property. I need help to prove the reflexivity one, i.e, $\varphi\sim \varphi$ for every rectifiable path $\varphi:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$.

Comment: How did you prove the symmetric property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just take $ f = I : [a, b]\to [a,b]$ the identity mapping. It's continuous, strictly increasing, and with $f(a) = a, f(b) = b$.